# How to deal with JSON and nested JSON inside a DataFrame columns into new columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame like below:

data type:

- COL1 - float
- COL2 - int
- COL3 - int
- COL4 - float
- COL5 - float
- COL6 - object
- COL7 - object

Source code:

```
a = pd.DataFrame()
a["COL1"] = [0.0, 800.0]
a["COL2"] = [2, 3]
a["COL3"] = [123, 444]
a["COL4"] = [1500.0, 1600.0]
a["COL5"] = [700.0, 850.0]
a["COL6"] = ['{"account": {"sector": 2, "other": 15}}', np.nan]
a["COL7"] = ['{"value": "ab"}', np.nan]
```

[image]

- COL6 and COL7 contain JSON, COL6 contains nested JSON.
- Furthermore there could be missings both in COL6 and COL7.
- And I need to convert values from COL6 and COL7 to "normal" form, however I can not even imagine how to convert COL6 (nested JSON) to DataFrame form of column with value

Desire output:

In terms of outpur for COL7 it is like below, however I can not even imagine how should look output for COL6 ?

```
COL1  | COL2 | COL3 | COL4   | COL5  | value |
------|------|------|--------|-------|-------|
0.0   | 2    | 123  | 1500.0 | 700.0 | abc   |
800.0 | 3    | 444  | 1600.0 | 850.0 | NaN   |
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

The following solution does not work: `pd.json_normalize(df['COL7'].apply(ast.literal_eval))`, ERROR: `ValueError: malformed node or string: nan`

Source code (be aware that if I read it in Pandas there is also NaN):

```
{'COL1': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'COL2': [2, 0, 33],
 'COL3': [2162561990, 2167912785, 599119703],
 'COL4': [1500.0, 500.0, 3500.0],
 'COL5': [750.0, 0.0, 3500.0],
 'COL6': ['{"account": {"sector": 4, "other": 10}
, "account_2": {"sector": 0, "other": 0}
, "account_3": {"sector": 6, "other": 8}}'],
 'COL7': ['{"value": "cc"
, "value_2": 15.58
, "value_3": 646}']}
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide desire output ?

Comment: R. Baraiya I added desire output, however it is difficult to me to imagine how should look output for values from COL6, do you have any idea ?

Comment: hows your input looks like before df? I mean from scratch, would be best to handle from there.

Comment: R. Baraiya, I do not understand, I added input DF and desire output, but as I mentioned I am not sure, how should look output for COL6

Comment: No I mean from where you getting your input and in which form? Also would mind to add 1-2 more rows to understand level of nested?

Comment: R. Baraiya I added at the end of question source code using: df.head().to_dict('list'), but be aware that it is only sample and for example both COL6.isna().any() and COL7.isna().any() is True :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250618/discussion-between-r-baraiya-and-dingaro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something as below; where you will first try to convert **json from nested to flat**,

more the error you were receiving that is because of nan values, so avoid that I have you if/else condition.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
import json 

for col in ['COL6', 'COL7']:
    a[col] = a[col].apply(lambda x: '' if pd.isnull(x) else list(pd.json_normalize(ast.literal_eval(x)).T.to_dict().values())[0])
a
```

#output

```
   COL1  COL2   COL3    COL4    COL5    COL6                           COL7
0   0.0     2   123 1500.0     700.0    {'account.sector': 2, 'account.other': 15}  ab
1   800.0   3   444 1600.0     850.0
```

after flatting, I am trying to split that column and concat with our actual data.

```
a = pd.concat([a, a['COL6'].apply(pd.Series).drop(0,axis=1)]], axis=1)
a.columns = a.columns.str.split('.').str[-1]
```

**Output**: you will get all columns, drop the unnecessary ones.

```
                sector          other
0                 2.0            15.0
1                 NaN             NaN
```

Comment: R. Baraiya I have error like the follow : KeyError: 'value' for this line a['COL7'] = a['COL7'].apply(lambda x: '' if pd.isnull(x)  else list(pd.json_normalize(ast.literal_eval(x)).T.to_dict().values())[0]['value'])

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, this might be a solution as well. By restructuring the data to dictionaries in a different format:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = '''{
    "COL1": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    "COL2": [2, 0, 33],
    "COL3": [2162561990, 2167912785, 599119703],
    "COL4": [1500.0, 500.0, 3500.0],
    "COL5": [750.0, 0.0, 3500.0],
    "COL6": [
        {
            "account": {"sector": 4, "other": 10}, 
            "account_2": {"sector": 0, "other": 0},
            "account_3": {"sector": 6, "other": 8}
        }
    ],
    "COL7": [
        {
            "value": "cc",
            "value_2": 15.58, 
            "value_3": 646}
        ]
    }

'''

d = json.loads(data)

d1, d2, d3 = {}, {}, {}
cols = []

for k in list(d.keys()):
    if not isinstance(d[k][0], dict):
        d1[k] = d[k][0]
        d2[k] = d[k][1]
        d3[k] = d[k][2]

    else:
        cols = list(d[k][0].keys())
        d1[cols[0]] = d[k][0][cols[0]]
        d2[cols[1]] = d[k][0][cols[1]]
        d3[cols[2]] = d[k][0][cols[2]]

df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(d1), pd.json_normalize(d2), pd.json_normalize(d3)], ignore_index = True))
```

yields:

```
       COL1  COL2        COL3    COL4    COL5 value  account.sector  account.other  value_2  account_2.sector  account_2.other  value_3  account_3.sector  account_3.other
    0   0.0     2  2162561990  1500.0   750.0    cc             4.0           10.0      NaN               NaN              NaN      NaN               NaN              NaN
    1   0.0     0  2167912785   500.0     0.0   NaN             NaN            NaN    15.58               0.0              0.0      NaN               NaN              NaN
    2   0.0    33   599119703  3500.0  3500.0   NaN             NaN            NaN      NaN               NaN              NaN    646.0               6.0              8.0
```